# Parsing an array in PHP after serializeArray() in JS

Tags: php, arrays

I receive this `array` in my PHP page after form serializeArray() done on a form in Javascript:

```
Array
(
    [datas] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => room_1
                    [value] => a
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => room_2
                    [value] => b
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => room_3
                    [value] => c
                )
        )
)
```

How can I parse it after during a foreach loop ?

Thanks.

---

I tried:

```
foreach ($datas as $key => $item) {
  echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($array['datas'] as  $item) {
  echo $item['name'];
  echo $item['value'];
}
```

Comment: @Misunderstood , too easy ;)

Comment: $array = $_POST['your_key'];  then you can use $array['datas']

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the array is $array,

```
$arr = $array['datas'];
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
  $name = $val['name'];
  $value = $val['value'];
  }
}
```

Comment: [datas]; should be ['datas']; and [value'] should be ['value']

Comment: Thanks. That's what happens when you get old.  There is a disconnect between mind and fingers. I can no longer type a single sentence without an error.   (e.g. typo in the word sentence just now).  I need a syntax checker to compliment the spell check.